# SQL / MySQL query (search for a flag change)?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, search

The database table contains a column with flags ("1" - working and "0" - not working process) and other fields, describing various characteristics of a machine during it / at the same time. What we need is to extract only the "rows", corresponding to condition change (flag change) - i.e. the row when the flag is first "1" (after that there would be other entries with "1", but are not at this point of any interest, just the first one), the row when it changes to "0" (there might be multiple entries with "0" after that), than the row when it changes to "1" again etc. We need this in one record (i.e., say, a variable S - the value of this variable when the flag changes to "1" and the value when the flag changes to "0").

Comment: can you show some sample data?

Comment: First in what order? Is there a date field?

Comment: Please also add an example for the requested result

Answer (score 0):

I would create another column called `change_handled`. Create a trigger so when the value of your flag changes, you set `change_handled=0`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER detect_flag_change BEFORE UPDATE ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW
 SET NEW.change_handled = (OLD.change_handled AND (NEW.flag = OLD.flag));
```

The `NEW.flag=OLD.flag` condition means that if the flag is changed as part of an update, the values will be different, so the equality will be false. Then change_handled will be set to false.

The `OLD.change_handled AND ...` condition means if a row is not handled, change_handled will be false, and it will therefore stay false, even if a subsequent UPDATE is applied to the row without changing the flag.

So once you have this column `change_handled`, you can search for rows where it's false (0).

Then I would guess you have some worker application that does something with the changed row. That application should lock the row in a transaction, by using UPDATE to set `change_handled=true`. But don't commit that transaction until the worker has finished its work. That way if the worker is interrupted, the update will be rolled back and then someone else can take care of it.